# Unable to access title or label of UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

For some reason I cannot access the `titleLabel` or `synopsisLabel` of a UITableViewCell in my app. Why is the compiler giving me these errors and how can I fix them?

[image: erroneous code]

Comment: You have to set the class of the cell in Interface Builder to your subclass.

Answer (score 1):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath, you have to deque a cell and cast it to your desired table view cell subclass.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Foo", for: indexPath) as! FooCell
```